# отправить кода php в базу данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql

я хочу отправить результат $K из кода кода PHP в базу данных MySQL,но что то сделал не так что не работает.

```
<html>

    <body >


<div class="cub">

           <h2>Тест</h2><hr>

        <br> 

        <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Nota" value="'.$k.'" />
        <?php echo $k;
```

mysql_query($sql);
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            $db = mysql_select_db("testare", $con);
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                        if(isset($_POST['Nota']))

```
mysql_select_db("testare",$con);

$sql="INSERT INTO test(nota)VALUES('.$k.')";}
            ?>
    <h1> Правильные ответы!</h1>


<input  type="submit" Value="Отправка"> <br>

                </form>



            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO test(nota)VALUES({'$k'}) зачем $k обернули в {}?

Comment: `не так что не работает.` Т.е. работает?

Comment: `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` можно удалить, ничего не делает.

Answer (score 0):

В строке `$sql="INSERT INTO test(nota)VALUES({'$k'})";` вы просто присвоили переменной выражение запроса, но нигде не запустили его на выполнение.
Требуется выполнить `mysql_query($sql);` и ждать, пока кто-то передаст в качестве параметра Nota значение `0'}); DROP TABLE test;--` или что-то в этом роде.